# Why is it safe to check in climbing gear onto a flight?

Tags: safety, rock-climbing, climbing

In the manual that comes with my rock climbing rope I bought (black diamond) there's a picture with a death sign when the temperature goes below -62 Celsius. Temperatures outside of planes reach well below this so it's possible the checked bag can hit less than -62 C. So how exactly is it safe to check in rock climbing gear?

Also, I'm afraid of the TSA manhandling my equipment.

Comment: Don't forget live animals (pets) also travel in the hold, and they don't like that kind of temperature either. But it's not outside

Comment: Many alloys undergo a ductile-to-brittle transition (dbt) as the temperature is lowered (well known to many mechanical engineering students and historians from WW2 Liberty ships). You don't want a piece trying to hold a fall below the dbt temperature. Bring the piece back up above that temperature and it will be just fine. Anyway, as @ChrisH points out, your rack will get nowhere near -62C in the plane hold. If you choose to carry on, expect a complete inspection of your rack at airport security and be sure not to have anything considered a danger (and it may get checked anyway).

Comment: @JonCuster, thinking purely hypothetically, if it was unloaded roughly while still below the DBT, it could get damaged.  But that would require (i) it to get that cold in the first place, which it won't in a pressurised aircraft, (ii) it to stay that cold until unloading - which would take a lot of insulation, and that would act as padding, and (iii) it to take a hard enough knock; packing well so it doesn't get slammed together would seem reasonable anyway.

Comment: @ChrisH - well, the actual failure curves of stress vs temperature would have to be looked at for some real case - the dbt temperature is where brittle failure will happen at the ductile maximum allowed stress. Lower stresses show a lower temperature for brittle fracture. Your gear in a bag sees no stresses remotely close to what it experiences in a fall, so will handle temperatures well below 62C and recover.

Comment: @JonCuster I agree - unless very badly packed and very badly dropped, which would also be a different type of loading  (compressive rather than tensile)

Comment: Now of course I finally parse the question to be with regard to the climbing rope, but frankly the same principles apply - an elastic to brittle transition in the polymer fibers. Unloaded there should be no issues.

Comment: Related on SE TRavel: [Will my checked luggage freeze in the airplane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22604/will-my-checked-luggage-freeze-in-the-airplane) The answer is NO.

Comment: Is there a way to label the checked bag as safety equipment? I feel it's putting in a bit too much trust in the baggage handlers that they won't damage the safety equipment

Comment: @JobHunter69 - I routinely put (full) wine bottles in checked baggage and have not lost one yet. If your bag doesn't burst open or get soaked with Jet-A, there really isn't anything that would impact the ratings of climbing equipment.

Comment: @JonCuster it's pointless to just say from experience that it hasn't happened yet when it comes to  life-death equipment. But maybe I'll just put a bottle of wine in the bag as a canary

Comment: @JobHunter69 - sure, I could phrase it better: if there is no obvious damage to your equipment and the bag holding it, there is no material failure mechanism that could be triggered by baggage handling.

Comment: +1 for the canary

Comment: @JobHunter69 I've heard that putting labels on luggage like 'fragile' can provoke bored handlers to treat it badly. What are they supposed to do with a bag that says 'safety equipment'? Perhaps they'll assume it must be very robust with that label and throw it around. Just make sure it is packed securely.

Comment: @JobHunter69 - I would bet that you do not always handle your climbing gear with the care you are asking TSA to.

Comment: @JonCuster I do treat all life equipment very carefully.

Comment: @JobHunter69 - and the baggage handlers treat all bags carefully, or so they will swear. Your pack with the rack inside was never dropped from waist high? Never slid down a slab? I think you need to think deeply about risk management and your current approach to it.

Comment: @ChrisH Although animals (pets) do sometimes travel in cargo holds, they do not always survive.  Three of many fatal examples: https://people.com/pets/dog-dies-air-france-plane/  and https://abcnews.go.com/Travel/traveling-pets-airlines-dog-deaths/story?id=11198807 and https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/may/02/the-cruelty-of-flying-animals-in-the-cargo-hold

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate they certainly get mistreated at times, but the hold of pressurised aircraft is designed to be suitable. Most of the animal deaths I've read about haven't been in the air, but on the ground - closed crates in hot sun for long periods, or forgotten in warehouses. The risk to animals in the air seems mainly to be stress combined with lack of access to food and water.

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks for your feedback.  I concur that, by design, the pressure and temperature should be suitable, but due to repeated failures it isn't.  Plus, as you mentioned, additional systemic failures can contribute to the deaths.  My point, which wasn't very clear by my quick comment (my apologies), is that sometimes conditions in the cargo hold aren't as they are designed to be.

Comment: Maybe -62°C is just the temperature at which the manufacturer had tested (an guaranties) the quality characteristics of the rope.

Answer (score 10):

As noted in comments by WeatherVane, the baggage area of a commercial flight will never approach anything near -62C. Sitting out on the wing, sure, but consider there is only a thin piece of aluminum between your feet and the baggage are, and your feet don't freeze (and pets and liquids, not to mention fresh flowers, are carried there routinely).

This still leaves the question of understanding just why there is a minimum temperature stated for use of the climbing rope (and potentially other climbing gear). This is because key material properties can change dramatically with temperature.

For many metal alloys (e.g. steel), there is a defined ductile-to-brittle transition temperature. Normally one expects steel to deform slightly (elastically) under stress, and then rebound completely when the stress is removed. If you exceed the maximum tensile (or shear) stress, one expects the material to deform more (plastically), yet stay in one piece until a much higher stress finally pulls it apart.

In contrast, when brittle, an applied stress can result in a small pre-existing crack (and all manufactured items have pre-existing cracks) to rapidly and uncontrollably extend through the material, breaking it in half. The classic example would be [Liberty Ships](https://metallurgyandmaterials.wordpress.com/2015/12/25/liberty-ship-failures/) in WW2. But, if there is not an applied stress, there will be no brittle failure.

Your rope is not a metal alloy, but similar principles apply for many polymers - above one temperature they are elastic, below it brittle. Folks living in cold regions know this well, where many normal commercial items (plastic buckets, windshield wipers) will just shatter in sub-zero temperatures. Again, such failure requires a stress to be applied (although sometimes internal stresses are enough). So, yes, the manufacturer of your rope is telling you that your rope will not perform to spec below -62C and may well break upon you taking a fall while the rope is that cold. (You, personally, are unlikely to work to spec at -62C as well.)

A bag of climbing gear should happily take a stint at -62C without major issues. There are no applied stresses (none approaching normal fall forces), so no driving force for brittle failure.

Comment: At one time, the aircraft hold was exposed to atmospheric temperature and pressure, but this changed in the later part of the 20th century, I'm not sure exactly when. However, the wheel housings have yet to get the upgrade, as many stowaways discover.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I believe that changed with jets operating at altitudes higher than the DC-3. They had to pressurize the cabin, and the stresses within the fuselage could not be tolerated if the baggage are was not also pressurized to match the cabin. That also means that the passenger cabin and baggage area partitions do not need to be sealed. Air flows intentionally between them (note there are not air intakes for circulation inside the passenger area - they are in the baggage area).

Comment: It certainly makes sense to seal the whole fuselage and not irregularly shaped parts of it.

Comment: I'd add to this *that your rope will not perform to spec below -62C and may well break upon you taking a fall while the rope is that cold.* part, that -62 C is very very cold and unless you are climbing very high altitude (Himalaya) or in very cold parts of Russia/Arctic or Antarctica, then you are very very unlikely to experience these sorts of temperatures.

Comment: @bob1 - indeed, I want no part of frolicking around in -62C.